# Unable to criteria search for matching map column (MapKeyColumn) in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity and want to find any entities with the same property set.

```
@Entity
public class PropertyResource {

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "property_key")
    @Column(name = "property_value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "resource_properties")
    private Map<String, String> properties = Maps.newHashMap();

    ...
}
```

This is my implementation using criteria builder:

```
public List<PropertyResource> findDuplicateProperties(PropertyResource resource) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PropertyResource> query = builder.createQuery(PropertyResource.class);
    Root<PropertyResource> resourceRoot = query.from(PropertyResource.class);
    List<Predicate> clauses = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : resource.getProperties().entrySet()) {
        MapJoin<PropertyResource, String, String> properties = resourceRoot.joinMap("properties", JoinType.INNER);
        clauses.add(builder.and(builder.equal(properties.key(), entry.getKey()), builder.equal(properties.value(), entry.getValue())));
    }
    if (!resource.isNew()) {
        clauses.add(builder.notEqual(resourceRoot.get("id"), resource.getID()));
    }
    clauses.add(builder.equal(resourceRoot.get("type"), resource.getType()));
    return em.createQuery(query.where(clauses.toArray(new Predicate[clauses.size()]))).getResultList();
}
```

I am doing an extra join per property. There are not many properties and resources with same type have the same property keys. This works great in h2 which produces this:

```
select ...
from resource_table propertyre0_ 
inner join resource_properties properties1_ on propertyre0_.entid=properties1_.PropertyResource_entid 
inner join resource_properties properties2_ on propertyre0_.entid=properties2_.PropertyResource_entid 
where properties1_.property_key=? and properties1_.property_value=? 
and properties2_.property_key=? and properties2_.property_value=? 
and propertyre0_.entid<>4 and propertyre0_.resource_type=?
```

For Oracle however I get this:

```
select ...
from resource_table propertyre0_ 
where propertyre0_.entid<>230 and propertyre0_.resource_type=?
```

Is there anything wrong in my query?

OBS: Almost forgot. Hibernate version is 4.1.9.Final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of user error (please replace user). My problem was that the properties map sent into the Oracle case was indeed empty. The code did the only right thing; it didn't create any joins.